# error in jsp : NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, jdbc

I have a MyDb class that `getConnetion` from existed database and a COURSES class that insert and update the courses table in data base . i use this class in my jsp file but when i run this its error :

```
http 500 error :
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

MYDB class :

```
public MYDB() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName(DRIVER);
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, UNAME, PASS);

    stmt = this.con.createStatement();
}

public Connection getCon() {
    return con;
}

public void setSQL(String SQL) throws SQLException {
    res = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
}
```

COURSES class :

```
public COURSES() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    MYDB c = new MYDB();

}

public void Insert(int id, String name, int unit) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    String SQL = "INSERT INTO courses VALUES(" + id + ",'" + name + "' , " + unit + ")";
    c.getStmt().executeUpdate(SQL);
}

public void updateName(int id, String newName) throws SQLException {
    String s = newName ;

    String SQL = "update courses set name=" + s + "where id is" + id;
    c.getStmt().executeUpdate(SQL);
}
```

jsp :

```
 <% 
        COURSES d = new COURSES() ;
        d.updateName(12, "op");
        %>
```

and this id exist befor in courses table . its insert func is ok and work .
where is my mistake ?

Comment: Can you add full stacktrace?

Comment: 1) Always give the full stacktrace of the exception. 2) Where's Jasper in any of your posted code?

Comment: Also this: `where id is" + id` must be `where id =" + id`

Comment: i do where id =" + id but again its not worked .

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor you assign a value to a *local* variable c:

```
public COURSES() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    MYDB c = new MYDB();
}
```

In the methods "Insert" and "updateName" you are then referencing an *instance variable* c that probably has not been initialized.

The constructor should probably look like this instead in order to initiate the instance variable:

```
public COURSES() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    c = new MYDB();
}
```